# How to sort a data frame with a column's last three integers in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting

| name | qty | id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| orange4 | 1 | 10pqw102 |
| orange3 | 2 | 10pxa920 |
| apple2 | 3 | 20asa399 |
| apple1 | 4 | 20asw987 |

### **Expected output**

| name | qty | id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| orange4 | 1 | 10pqw102 |
| apple2 | 3 | 20asa399 |
| orange3 | 2 | 10pxa920 |
| apple1 | 4 | 20asw987 |

Comment: can you add some detail to your post, as well as your own effort and expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `key` parameter in [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
df = df.sort_values(by='id', key=lambda col: col.str[-3:].astype(int))
```

For oldier pandas versions:

```
df = df.iloc[df['id'].str[-3:].astype(int).argsort()]
```

Comment: or `df.sort_values(df['ColC'].str.extract('(\d{3}$)').astype(int))`  but i think OP wants to be sorted by `ID` column not ColC

Comment: @Manakin - thank you, it was first OP data.